# Can I use Google Analytics to sort out the statistics of my iOS App?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is this a violation of Apple app development rules? In some forums I just saw that thing. So am afraid of getting rejected by AppStore if I use the same. Help me with this please. And if I can't use Google Analytics SDK then which will be the best analytics method I could implement for my App?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not legal advice, but, as of right now, no apps have been rejected by Apple for using Google Analytics.

Google has released an official [iOS Google Analytics SDK](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/), and there is no record of Apple explicitly forbidding or discouraging its use.

Google Analytics is the most widely used analytics solution around, and unless your operations are based out of Germany, you likely have little to worry about.

Comment: @yahelc: does that mean that there might be the problems when using google analytics in apps that will be used in Germany?

Comment: @Centurion not anymore. http://www.stateofsearch.com/google-analytics-can-be-used-in-germany-without-complaint/ It might still be advisible to use the [`anonymizeIP`](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/iphone/#anonymizeIp) function that the iOS SDK provides if this concerns you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Google Analytics vs Apple rules, but if you're just looking for any way to have stats, have a look at [Flurry Statistics](http://www.flurry.com/product/analytics/index.html) - it's quite powerful and completely free. Also I never heard of any legal issues with it (I think you just need to inform users in your app's EULA that you collect data to make the application better).

Answer (score 2):

my name is Peter and I'm with Flurry.  Thanks to delirus for pointing out that we have a free service.  We support iOS, Android, BlackBerry, WP7 and JavaME.  Regarding iOS, we have no knowledge that any app has been rejected during the app submission process due to the inclusion of Flurry Analytics.  Over 38,000 companies use Flurry Analytics. You can learn more at www.flurry.com.  Thanks, Peter

Comment: Flurry is a great free service we use it in many iOS apps. (one little complaint is that sometimes the API changes either from iOS SDK or flurry break the app).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, James. If you ever experience API problems in the future, please email us at support@flurry.com.  We want to have the chance to address this as soon as possible.

Comment: Is it a requirement to let the user 'opt out' of analytics recording, say in the settings app? If it's not a requirement, I'd still add the switch in.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics is under scrutiny in certain regions of this planet because some people believe they are not respecting data protection laws and legislation.

So even if Apple accepts your app you run the risk of somebody filling a complaint with Apple and as result your app could be withdrawn at a later stage.

If you don't know yourself which analytic tool is best for your needs then I assume you have not really thought about what data you really require. Take a moment or two to come up with a list of requirements and then start looking for the tool best matching the needs.

Comment: Thats a good piece of information. I think I should contact in detail with any Apple people. Thanks a lot OLAF..

Comment: In addition to the technical requirements the OP needs to understand if the tool is legal to use for the intended target market and if the intended target audience will accept software that phones home. The friendly users block at their firewall, the others won't purchase it in the first place.

Comment: @YC we can play the your childish game of rolling back your edits to my answer all week, but if you only indent to promote your own opinion I expect you to first grow up a bit

Comment: my edits have nothing to do with my opinion, unless my opinion is that Google Analytics is the name of a brand, and thus under the standards of English grammar, should be capitalized, and that "of this planet" is totally redundant, unless you're not worried about privacy laws on the Moon.