# Analytics in iOS App - Request user consent

Tags: ios, google-analytics, analytics, privacy, google-analytics-sdk

I'm debating whether to include (Google) analytics in my iOS app. Obviously I would like the analytics data, but my concern is whether to simple advise the user that data is being collected, or to specifically request their consent.

Is specific consent required, or can one simple inform the user via a loading page or website privacy policy page? Apple has a rule on consent, but does this necessarily translate into displaying a dialogue box with a Agree/Disagree buttons?

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because policy questions are off-topic (and [so are app stores](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/6296561))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand this, you can add information about data collection to a privacy policy, of course if you didn't collect some specific information. If it's just user activity in the app I think you can leave it in the policy.

Moreover, not so long ago, Apple made privacy policy a required thing. Add info about data collection there and if someone is curious enough to read it will know about it.

You can also read this question about this topic: [Can I use Google Analytics to sort out the statistics of my iOS App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894803/can-i-use-google-analytics-to-sort-out-the-statistics-of-my-ios-app)